# How to include an external HTML-Head?

Tags: javascript, html, include, seo, html-head

I'm back to coding a small business website and it seems silly to have like 40% duplicate code (head and menu) across 10 HTML-pages. On the other hand, it also seems overkill to throw something like [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) at such a small project.

Is there a simple way to mitigate the duplicate code by including a head.html within every page either server- or client-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer PHP.  Change your .html (static) pages into .php (dynamic) pages.  Just 'save as'.  You can separate pretty much anything into templates.

You have the following simplified file structure:

```
index.php

header.php

home.php

footer.php

style.css
```

The `index.php` contains   + calls the `header.php` + `home.php` + `footer.php`

The `header.php` has your menus, etc.

the `home.php` can have your slider, and more sections, etc.

the `footer.php` has your menus + copyright, etc.

the `style.css` has your styles and you can have many `.css` files depending what you want styled.

You can expand this to your other pages:  `about.php`, `services.php`, `contact.php`, etc.

Into `index.php` file you add something like

```
<?php require ('your-folder-for-content/header.php'); ?>

<?php require ('your-folder-for-content/home.php'); ?>

<?php require ('your-folder-for-content/footer.php'); ?>
```

Close `</html>` bracket at the end of your footer.

One page or little repeated sections call the other and redundancy is prevented.

Comment: How is the home.php switched out for different content?

Comment: @leonheess home.php is on your landing page as you know. The switching out for other pages happens in the header when you link pages and you may have even have different headers later for different areas of your content.  However, the landing page is the first visit.  Let's say, you add a slider to your home.php, call it with <?php require ("your-folder-for-content/slider1-home.php" ?> for example.  You want to add a contact section to your bottom of your landing page before footer, add <?php require ("your-folder-for-content/contact-bottom.php"  ?>. Home page will give you a clean oversight.

Comment: @leonheess Whatever you change later in those 'calls' with 'require', even if you repeat in other pages, such as call the same section in another page, even if it is a button.php, you will be able to change the content of these sections as you wish and it will change at once.  You will not need to search around inside a huge mess of code and the structure will become more evident what page calls what page/ content.   Each page will have less clutter and content can be kept easily changeable. Start simple.  You will see what I mean.

Comment: @leonheess Also, you may opt to work on a template website.  I will recommend Bootstrap.  Bootstrap has a standardized layout system.  It already comes with beautiful elements.  Look for a template website here:  https://startbootstrap.com/themes/.  Pick a free template and see how it works.  Change the elements and content to your liking.  Drop pages you do not need.  Have a quick start-up to your small business website.  For the contact page, if you get stuck, find me here.  I can recommend you a neat program that is highly developed and comes for free.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with client JavaScript coz it running after header parsing. You should use server side technologies for this. From SSI to PHP :)

Comment: What is SSI? Google says Scuba Schools International

Comment: Server Side Includes technology

Comment: Is this actually still the way to go? If I research this I only get old resources..

Comment: Cos it is very old technology. But it working now too. And this is simplest way to do your task.

Comment: Would you recommend PHP or SSI?

Comment: depends on your preferences and which software on server you used...

Answer (score 1):

[Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com) is pretty good and easy to use. You can strip off all the features you don't need. Has template filling available as well. It outputs static html for the whole site, so you don't need your server to be running any daemons.