# Navbar Not Displaying on All Pages

Tags: html, nav

I want to show my navigation bar on all pages, however I do not want to copy paste the same code into all html files. I tried to put the navigation bar code into a different file navigation.html and then using a script to load it back into index.html but it's not working. Does anyone know where I made a mistake?

This is navigation.html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">M M N</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="ABC - Resume.pdf">RESUME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                PHOTOGRAPHY
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="A.html">A</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="B.html">B</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="C.html">C</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="D.html">D</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>ABC</title>
</head>    
<body>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--Navigation bar-->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="nav-placeholder"></div>

    <script>
      $(function(){
      $("#nav-placeholder").load("navigation.html"); 
      });
    </script>
    <!--end of Navigation bar-->

    <div class="container mt-5">
    <h1>ABC</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <p>
                ABC
            </p>
            <p>
                ABC
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="ABC.jpg" alt="ABC" style="width:50%">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>

<footer class="pt-2 my-md-2 pt-md-2 border-top elegant-color-dark">
  <div class="row justify-content-center elegant-color-dark">
    <div>
        <p>© ABC.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</footer> 
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Comment: I tried this link before but it doesn't work.

Comment: which language you are using as backend? if you are using.

Comment: Not using, only have html files

Answer (score 1):

your can use ajax to load the content

```js
<script>
 $(function(){     
  $.ajax({  
    type: "GET",
    url: "navigation.html",  
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(answer) {  
   $("body").append(answer);  
    },
    error: function(){
   alert("failed call!!!");
    } 
  }); 
  return false;  
 });
</script>
```

Comment: This is not working. I tried to put it into index.html inside body but I still don't see the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

If your navigation bar is going to be the header of your website, traditionally, it is named header.html.

I prefer using .php instead of .html to link pages with each other.  Here is the link where I explained in detail:

[ [How to include an external HTML-Head?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58318334/how-to-include-an-external-html-head/58331433#58331433])